# for some reason the user is not updated

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to add to the user a field with paths to its created files, it is an array `pathArray`,but for some reason it is not updated `await userService.updateUser({ _id }, { photos: pathArray });`,
the service itself `updateUser: (user, updatedUser) => User.updateOne(user, updatedUser)`,
the service returns such an object `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`
User model:

```
  photos: {
    type: Array
  }
```

`{ photos: pathArray }`-an array that looks like this:

```
{
  photos: [
    {
      pathForDB: 'users\\60e6c6e56d2df72d1881c57a\\photos\\8bd722f0-e22d-11eb-b487-df8a875defa8.jpg',
      timestamp: '11.07.2021, 12:51:21'
    },
    {
      pathForDB: 'users\\60e6c6e56d2df72d1881c57a\\photos\\8be18330-e22d-11eb-b487-df8a875defa8.jpg',
      timestamp: '11.07.2021, 12:51:21'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes that's expected, that's what Mongoose returns. What's the problem?

Comment: however, the user is not updated

Comment: But how do you know that? You say nothing about how you check whether it was updated or not

Comment: I check on robo3t

Comment: Ah, then I admit that's weird. Did you make sure you refreshed your collection in Robo3T? With F5 etc

Comment: yes, several times

Answer (score 0):

It's better you find the user with User.findOne() then update and save it back. With this method, you can always retrieve the updated data.

```
const user =User.findOne({
  _id: userId
});
user.files= pathArray //method to update
const result = await user.save()
res.status(200).json({
  user: result
});
```

Comment: it does not want to change the object,returns the same object

Comment: Aaaah I have the solution for this one. You must add 'markModified' : `user.files= pathArray; user.markModified("files"); await user.save();`

Answer (score 0):

`User.updateOne(user, updatedUser)` is an asynchronous block of code, which needs an `await` keyword before it

so your function may look something like this

```
updateUser: async (user, updatedUser) => await User.updateOne(user, updatedUser)
```

Comment: the same problem

Comment: are you sure the _id exists? could you console.log(_id) and show the result here?